# Microsoft USD, open a new tab for Hosted control after button click from c#

Tags: unified-service-desk

I have a requirement to open a Hosted Control on click of a button from another hosted control. The issue is that i have done it using javascript with the below code.

```
 var actionCallData = "action=" + actionName + " " + "%0D%0A";
        actionCallData += "application=" + applicationName + " " + "%0D%0A";
        actionCallData += "data=" + data;
        window.open("http://uii/CRM Global Manager/CallDoAction?" + 
actionCallData);
```

i want to implement same thing from c# code.
any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Having one control call another in C# would be a tightly-coupled approach, which is not recommended. Instead, take the loosely-coupled approach: Define your Action Call as a configuration record, and trigger it using a C# event.

Here's how to fire an event using C#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/unified-service-desk/create-user-defined-event#use-the-fireevent-action

Be sure to add the configuration Event record to your Hosted Control, and relate it to your Action Call. If your Event needs to pass data into the Action Call, be sure to include that data in your FireEvent call. I believe the data type for event parameters is Dictionary of string and string.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. I actually forgot to update my answer. I have done the same thing you have mentioned, and its working.